# Thymeleaf java template engine is changing some special characters

Tags: java, thymeleaf, template-engine

```
final Context ctx = new Context();
context.setVariable("data", data);
templateEngine.process(template, context).trim();
```

here are the imports:

```
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
```

template variable points to "content_completed". Where this content_completed is a html file that exists in the project classpath.

contents of this html file:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:inline="text" th:remove="tag">
[[${data.fileName}]][[${T(abc.composer.NoteData).COMPLETED_NO_ERRORS}]]
</html>
```

where NoteData is a java class

If this **data.fileName** has something like "sample&.text", the Thymeleaf template engine is changing it to "sample&amp;.text".

Any thoughts on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. Here is the solution:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:inline="text" th:remove="tag">
<th:block th:utext="${data.fileName}"/>[[${T(abc.composer.NoteData).COMPLETED_NO_ERRORS}]]
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf is escaping the filename so that a browser does not interpret the `&` as a special HTML character (it's used for HTML entities).

So, the answer, I think, is that it's doing the right thing. When you view the HTML output in a browser it will render as you are expecting.

Comment: What should i do, if i do not want to escape these characters? Because, i am using this html file for emailNotifications

Comment: If your email is an HTML email, you need it to do the same escaping. HTML requires you to escape raw ampersands. The mail readers will show the message correctly.

Comment: The senders are showing it as &amp; instead of the original one. Any thoughts?

Comment: My bad, i typed emailNotifications instead of text. Having problems with texts, email works just fine.

Comment: Why are you using Thymeleaf if you don't want XML / HTML?